# How to bind DataTable of custom objects to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a list comprising of two other lists of custom objects that are linked by an Id. Essentially I have an 'CPDActivity' object that has many properties and an 'CPDActivityExtended' object with several more. I then have a 'CPDActivityComplete' object that contains one each of the other objects. These complete objects get added to a list which is what populates a DataTable.

I need to be able to bind this DataTable to a GridView and display the values of the properties of the CPDActivityComplete's two child objects. For example CPDActivityComplete.CPDActivity.A under an 'A' column.

Here is a basic picture of what I'm trying to do:
[image]

The list of custom objects visualised:
[image]

What I have tried so far:

The DataTables are populated using Entity Framework & LINQ and I have bound the GridView to the resulting DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = getCPDData.ToDataTable<CPDActivityComplete>(cpdActivityCompleteList);
cpd_gv_activities.DataSource = dt;
cpd_gv_activities.DataBind();
```

I have a simple GridView to test things out:

```
<asp:GridView ID="cpd_gv_activities" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="15">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Name">
        <ItemStyle CssClass="fixedcell"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="vd_gv_lbl_FullName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CPDActivity.A") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>   
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

But this results in an error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'A'.
```

How do I bind the label.text to CPDActivityExtended.CPDActivity.A property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to a strongly typed GridView. Then you have easy access to all the properties and type-safety.

So first add the `ItemType` to the GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="cpd_gv_activities" runat="server" ItemType="YourNameSpace.CPDActivityComplete">
```

Now you can use `Item` in the GridView and access properties

```
<asp:Label ID="vd_gv_lbl_FullName" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.A %>'></asp:Label>
```

And last, don't convert to a DataTable (was not needed in the first place) but bind the List with the class directly.

```
cpd_gv_activities.DataSource = cpdActivityCompleteList;
cpd_gv_activities.DataBind();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Great answer, thank you!  I have made the changes you suggested and everything is working now.