# How to display images in grid view asp control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I use datatable as data source for grid view.
And one of the columns of the data table have to display image.

Here is how I create data table:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
List<ReportFeature> featureProps = fim.getFeatureProperties().ToList();

var headers = featureProps.FirstOrDefault().Properties.Select(k => k.Key).ToList();
headers.ForEach((h) => dt.Columns.Add(h, typeof(string)));

foreach (var feat in featureProps)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
        row[header] = feat.Properties[header];  
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

And here is how I bind the data table to grid view datas source:

```
gvfeatureProps.DataSource = dt;
gvfeatureProps.DataBind();
```

one of the columns in data table contains path to image.
My question is how do I make images displayed in my grid view after bind programatically?

Comment: You can bind the list `featureProps` directly to the GridView. No need to convert it to a DataTable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962471/how-to-bind-datatable-of-custom-objects-to-gridview

Comment: Property names are being used as column header per default. You only need to change that behavior if the property name should NOT be the column header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an image programatically, use the RowDataBound event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //create a new cell
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();

        //create an image
        Image img = new Image();
        img.ImageUrl = row["imageUrl"].ToString();

        //add the image to the cell
        cell.Controls.Add(img);

        //add the cell to the gridview
        e.Row.Controls.Add(cell);

        //or use addat if you want to insert the cell at a certain index
        e.Row.Controls.AddAt(0, cell);

        //or don't add a new cell but add it to an existing one (replaces original content)
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for post!how can I access to the text of the cells inside GridView1_RowDataBound event?

Comment: You don't have to, use `row["columnName"]`

Comment: Yes , I know. but I need to get text from each cell in GridView1_RowDataBound event to get imageUrl

Comment: `e.Row.Cells[i].Text`

Comment: That is a no break space. But that means an empty cell.

Answer (score 2):

All within `<Columns>` you can also use template fields

Using a asp.net Image:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("MyImageUrlColumnName") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

or the standard HTML img:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img src='<%# Eval("MyImageUrlColumnName") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you need a bit more flexibility that the ImageField used in previous answer.

Comment: You mean the column name can change?